# Где должен быть родительский файл pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

Создал проект с 2 модулями и хотел сделать родительский pom чтобы не писать все дважды, не знаю где должен быть родительский пом.
Заранее спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где Вы сделали два модуля?

Comment: добавил фото, shop это модули

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этой же папке создаем pom.xml родительского проекта примерно такого содержания:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>someGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>someArtifactId</artifactId>
    <version>someVersion</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>shop_category</module>
        <module>shop_product</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Замените `someGroupId`, `someArtifactId`, `someVersion` на удобочитаемые координаты проекта.

У каждого дочернего модуля в POM.xml нужно будет проставить ссылку на родителя:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>someGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>someArtifactId</artifactId>
    <version>someVersion</version>
</parent>
...
```

На примере все это можно посмотреть в [Maven by Example. Chapter 6. A Multi-Module Project](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html).

P.S. На самом деле pom.xml можно разместить практически где угодно и проекты могут ссылаться друг на друга через прописанные пути, но, скорее всего, Вам это не нужно.